# Combine 2 variables inside postgres procedure

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables: post, tag, and tag_post

post holds the actual posts, tags holds the tags that have been created so far and tag_post holds the relation between them.
When a new post is created, 4 things happen:

- all tags that dont exist yet are created
- the post is created
- all the tag_post relations are created
- the newly created post is returned to the function caller

These are the tables

```
/*
POST TABLES
*/

CREATE TABLE tag(
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    check(name!='')
);

CREATE TABLE post(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    title text,
    url text,
    author text NOT NULL references profile(name)
);

CREATE TABLE tag_post(
    tag text REFERENCES tag(name),
    post uuid REFERENCES post(id),
    UNIQUE (tag, post)
);
```

Heres how I did that:

```
/*
CREATE A NEW POST
 */
 
create or replace function create_post(
    author text,
    title text,
    url text,
    tags text[]

)
RETURNS post
as $$
DECLARE 
inserted record;
begin

    INSERT INTO tag(name)
    SELECT v
    FROM unnest(tags) g(v)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;


    INSERT INTO post(author, title, url) 
    values(author,title,url) 
    RETURNING * INTO inserted;

    INSERT INTO tag_post(tag,post)
    SELECT g.v, inserted.id FROM
    unnest(tags) g(v);


    RETURN inserted;

END $$
language plpgsql;
```

Now I would also like to return the array of tags that was passed to the function together with the inserted row. basically something like this (which doesn't work, just for demonstaration):

```
SELECT inserted.*, tags as tags FROM inserted join tags INTO inserted;
```

But I don't know how to combine 2 variables into a single one. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by "combine 2 variables into a single one", that seems to what the final query is doing. Do you mean to concatenate variables? Also post sample data - as text, **no images** - and the expected results from that data.

Comment: Basically add tags to the existing columns in inserted

Comment: Need sample data and results. That is exactly what your query "SELECT inserted.*, tags as tags FROM inserted join tags INTO inserted;" does.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the `CREATE` statements for the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I did it:

```
SELECT row_to_json(sel)
FROM
(
    SELECT inserted.*,tags
) sel
INTO inserted2;

RETURN inserted2;
```

inserted2 is a json variable